# Vocabulary about shape of some functions

Tags: functions, terminology, elliptic-curves

Do functions having two separated curves (or more) like that one when plotted (that's a special elliptic function) have a special name?

[image]

Thx for your feedback

Comment: V.I. Arnold in his nice booklet *Real Algebraic Geometry* calls this a *nondegenerate curve* because the equation has no multiple roots (this one has three distinct roots). He does not distinguish it though from the nondegenerate curve that has only a single root, say, $y^2=x^3-x+1$ where the graph becomes connected. Curves with multiple roots he calls degenerate.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what you’re referring to as “functions” here. To decompose this graph into the graphs of two functions, you’d have to split it along the $x$ axis, but that doesn’t seem to be what you have in mind. I suspect that you don’t actually mean functions in the usual sense of the term, but graphs of relations. In your example, the graph you show is the graph of the relation $y R x\Leftrightarrow y^2=x^3-x$ (which is not a function, even when restricted to $[-1,0]\cup[1,\infty)$, because there are two $y$ values for each $x$ value).

This graph is [disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space); more specifically, it consists of two [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components). This is a general topological concept that can be applied to all sets, not just to graphs of relations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback